C# Access Modifier Scopes
I have following block of code, where I have multiple instances of Class Lane. I want to compare 2 Objects and check if there is space or not.
public class Lane
{
        private int _filledSpots = 0;
        public bool IsSpaceAvailable(Lane fromLane)
        {
            return fromLane._filledSpots == 4;
        }
}

Now to the issue. My understanding is that in following method, I cannot access _filledSpots property of fromLane. But VS Code is not giving any errors. How is this possible? Or I have wrong understanding of access scopes.

What is "following method"? Do you mean IsSpaceAvailable? What made you think this shouldn't be possible? Which documentation page (presumably you have read those) made you think so?

The code that accesses that field is inside the class, so it is able to access private members. 'Private' specifically means accessible only inside the same class. You are presumably confused because it's a private member of a different instance but that's irrelevant. It's the same class so all members are accessible.
Being able to access private members of other instances of the same class is required in order for copy constructors to be universally effective. Otherwise, any type with a private field could not have a copy constructor because you could not get that value to set it in the new instance.
For the record, a copy constructor would look something like this:
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(SomeClass otherInstance)
    {
        SomeFieldOrProperty = otherInstance.SomeFieldOrProperty;
        // Etc.
    }
}

Without the ability to access private members of the other instance, you couldn't copy all the data it contains unless it was all exposed via public members.

Why is this code in VB.NET when the question is tagged as C# (and I don't know if Unity accepts anything from .NET but C#)?

@MaxPlay, I added the code example later and had been answering VB questions and forgot this one was C#. Fixed.
